# getpeerinfo peer port number

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, regtest

Working on regtest (Bitcoin Core 0.15.1) I've realized that some peers are identified just by `ip` instead of by `ip:port` when querying `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo`. I've noticed that when it happens the connection is always outbound, so the port is actually the one set in the node (in this case `18444`), but it doesn't happens with all outbound connections. Does anyone have a clue about what could be the reason?

e.g:

`{
    "id": 41,
    "addr": "172.192.0.5",
    "addrlocal": "172.192.0.2:56402",
    "addrbind": "172.192.0.2:56402",
    "services": "000000000000000d",
    "relaytxes": true,
    "lastsend": 1516808394,
    "lastrecv": 1516808394,
    "bytessent": 17600,
    "bytesrecv": 93216,
    "conntime": 1516786190,
    "timeoffset": 0,
    "pingtime": 0.000588,
    "minping": 0.000101,
    "version": 70015,
    "subver": "/Satoshi:0.15.1/",
    "inbound": false,
    "addnode": true,
    "startingheight": 1,
    "banscore": 0,
    "synced_headers": 101,
    "synced_blocks": 101,
    "inflight": [
    ],
    ...
}`

Just in case it could matter, all nodes are docker containers connected to the same virtual network (all hosted by the same computer).